# android 4.1.2: copy file within /system/fonts in recovery mode

Tags: android, rooted-device

my Samsung S2 does not boot anymore because I deleted the file

```
/system/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf
```

I have a copy of this file as

```
/system/fonts/Helvetica.ttf
```

How can I copy Helvetica.ttf to Roboto-Regular.ttf in recovery mode?

I have a rooted phone and use PhilZ-cwm6-XWMS2-MOT-5.15.9

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem myself.
For anybody having a similar issue:

As mentioned above, I use the rooted kernel PhilZ-cwm6-XWMS2-MOT-5.15.9.
This can also be installed by a zip-file within the recovery mode.

The simple solution now was to modify the shell-script inside this zip-file:
At the end of this shell-script, right before the "exit"-command, I wrote the following shell-commands

```
# to be sure that /system (still) is mounted read-write:
mount -o remount,rw /system
# copying the font-file:
cp /system/fonts/Helvetica.ttf /system/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf
```

Then I only had to copy the modified zip-file to a micro-sd-card, insert this into the phone, start recovery mode, where I chose from the menu: install zip-file > (external) sdcard > install ...

Then I rebooted the phone, et voilà.

Of course, this also reinstalled the kernel, which was not needed but also not a problem to me. (Before doing the above I tried to start a very simple script in a custom zip-file with the "install zip-file" command, to prevent going through the whole procedure of kernel-installation, but did not succeed with this trick. Maybe someone else can find a way.)